# Is there a way to assign a default YYYY when importing to Rails from csv?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I've been give a .csv with birthdays, but month and day only. How would I go about inserting a default year, say 2020, either in excel or when importing into Postgres, Rails. Wracking brain.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a code example. Without it's hard to help you out.
If I was able to understand your problem you just need to parse a date.

```rb
CSV.foreach(file, col_sep: ';', headers: true) do |row|
  data = row.to_h.transform_keys(&:strip)
  birthday = Date.parse("2020-#{data['month']}-#{data['day']}")
end
```